# Internal error 51 when calculating with time variables

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that calculate the average speed of all the employees. But it throws an error when trying to execute it. The weird part is that it works just fine on my computer at home but not at the computer at work. This is the code that causes the error:

```
ReDim employeespeed(1 To UBound(employeelist))
Dim oneHour As Date
oneHour = #1:00:00 AM#

For i = 1 To UBound(employeelist)
    employeespeed(i) = (oneHour / totaltimeworked(i)) * employeeresult(i) 'THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR 51
Next i
```

`totaltimeworked` is an array which outputs values like `12:34:56 AM` (34 minutes and 56 seconds)

`empolyeeresult` outputs a number, like `113`

Typing it out directly on the sheet works though which is weirder. Like:

```
=sum(B20/B21*B22)
```

Where `1:00:00 AM` is put in the cell `B20` and the output from the arrays are put in the cells `B21` and `B22`.

But it doesn't work in VBA.

Anyone knows why this might be?

Comment: Just a guess... but I would work with numeric types instead of date types, e.g. 1 hour = 1/24. What are the types of `employeespeed`, `totaltimeworked`, etc.?

Comment: employeespeed is an integer, totaltimeworked is a date.

Comment: How would you use 1/24 is the calculation? employeespeed(i) = (1/24)/totaltimeworked(i) * employeeresult(i) ?

Comment: `Dim oneHour as Double`, `oneHour = 1/24`.

Comment: It worked on my computer here at home! Have to try it tomorrow on the computer at work! Thank you!

Comment: Rule of thumb, avoid doing math with `Date` values.

Comment: It didn't work, same error...is there a way to convert the date value to an integer? Like 23 min and 30 seconds becomes 23,5? I tried totalminutes(i) = Left(Right(totaltime(i))), 5), 2) to get the minutes but it showed Type mismatch (error 13)

Comment: I solved it! (I think) Hopefully it will work on the computer at work. `ReDim totalminutes(1 To UBound(employeelist)) As Double, totalminutes(i) = (totaltimeworked(i)) * 1440, employeespeed(i) = (60 / totalminutes(i)) * employeeresult(i)`